# When I compile Java(fx) application for Android, with the SoundPool use, the java compiler says "package android.media does not exist"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, soundpool, javafxports

In a Java application for Android, made in JavaFX under Eclipse Neon2, I want to use the android media SoundPool class.

To do that, I have added, in the Java Build Path:

- the android-sdks platform : android-25 (called android.jar).
- the jfxdvk-8.60.8.jar

Then, for instance, I create a SoundPool instance as follows:

```
import android.media.SounPool;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;

...
SoundPool sp = new SoundPool(MAX_STREAMS,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
```

The syntax is correct and the Eclipse editor does not notice any error.

But, when compiling the file, I have two errors "package android.media does not exist import android.media.AudioManager" and "package android.media does not exist import android.media.SoundPool;", and then, (it is a consequence), "cannot find symbols" at "AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC" and at "new SoundPool" of the previous line code.

I don't understand these errors because I have added, in my JavaBuild Path, this android-sdks platform: android.jar (android-25) ad the Eclipse editor can fetch these two imports.

Thanks in advance for your response

---

**Further information:**

Errors raised on java compilation:

```
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
[sts] Starting Gradle build for the following tasks: 
[sts]      androidInstall
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
:validateManifest
:collectMultiDexComponents
:compileJavaC:\Users\pascal\workspaceNeon\JFX_withGluon_11.0gAvecSoundPoolKO\src\main\java\com\gluonapplication\GluonApplication.java:3: error: package android.media does not exist
import android.media.AudioManager;
                    ^
C:\Users\pascal\workspaceNeon\JFX_withGluon_11.0gAvecSoundPoolKO\src\main\java\com\gluonapplication\GluonApplication.java:4: error: package android.media does not exist
import android.media.SoundPool;
                    ^
C:\Users\pascal\workspaceNeon\JFX_withGluon_11.0gAvecSoundPoolKO\src\main\java\com\gluonapplication\GluonApplication.java:635: error: cannot find symbol
    static SoundPool androidSoundPoolApplication = null;

----------------------
Related code:
package com.gluonapplication;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;

import com.gluonhq.charm.down.Services; // line 3
import com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.AccelerometerService; // line 4

......

    final static int MAX_STREAMS = 10;
    static SoundPool androidSoundPoolApplication = null;  // line 635
```

---

And the build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.3.0'
}

jfxmobile {
     downConfig {
        version '3.2.0'
        plugins 'accelerometer', 'compass', 'device', 'orientation', 'storage', 'vibration', 'display', 'magnetometer', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'position'
    }

android {
        applicationPackage = 'com.gluonapplication'
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        androidSdk = 'C:/Users/pascal/AppData/Local/Android/sdk'
        resDirectory = 'src/android/res'
        compileSdkVersion = '25'
        buildToolsVersion = '25.0.1'
      }

 ios {
         infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` to your gradle file.

Comment: Why are you adding the Android API to the Main sources? It needs to be included only under the Android sources. Then you'll need a service to call it from the main class, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38419634/javafxports-how-to-call-android-native-media-player/42160145) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42934078/3956070).